# implementing automatic deletion of a (related) row of record in PartyEvent table, when a row from the Client table is deleted

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE PARTY_EVENT
(
    passport_number VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
    event_id        DECIMAL(10)  NOT NULL,
    event_date      DATE         NOT NULL,
    event_time      CHAR(5)      NOT NULL,
    event_venue     VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    party_size      CHAR(3)      NOT NULL,
    cuisine_package VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PARTY_EVENT_PK PRIMARY KEY(event_id),
    CONSTRAINT PARTY_EVENT_FK  
        FOREIGN KEY(passport_number) REFERENCES CLIENT(passport_number)
             ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT PARTY_EVENT_FK1 
        FOREIGN KEY(passport_number) REFERENCES CHEF  (passport_number)
             ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT PARTY_EVENT_CK2 UNIQUE(event_date, event_time, event_venue)
);

ALTER TABLE PARTY_EVENT 
DROP FK_passport_number;
```

Error:

> ALTER TABLE PARTY_EVENT
> DROP FK_passport_number
>
> Error Code: 1091. Can't DROP 'FK_passport_number'; check that column/key exists

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions as you've not specified the exact question:

1. I expect you'd like to drop a constraint as your code drops the constraint which should be:

> ```
> ALTER TABLE PARTY_EVENT 
> DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Passport_Number
> ```

If you'd want to drop the column passport:

```
ALTER TABLE PARTY_EVENT
DROP COLUMN passport_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your create table statement, there is no `fk_passport_number` constraint, I'm assuming you meant `party_event_fk` and `party_event_fk1`.

You first need to drop the foreign key constraint:

MySQL:

```sql
ALTER TABLE party_event DROP FOREIGN KEY party_event_fk;
ALTER TABLE party_event DROP FOREIGN KEY party_event_fk1;
```

SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:

```sql
ALTER TABLE party_event DROP CONSTRAINT party_event_fk;
ALTER TABLE party_event DROP CONSTRAINT party_event_fk1;
```

Then you can drop the actual column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE party_event DROP COLUMN passport_number;
```

The problem was that you were trying to drop the constraint like it was a column.